# How to prevent OllyDbg from interpreting parameters?

Tags: configuration, ollydbg

How do you prevent OllyDbg from interpreting parameters and showing the registernames + offset instead?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ALT+O (options)
Analyis
uncheck ahow recognized args

screen shot with show recognized args checked 
[image]

screen shot with show recognized args  unchecked

[image]